# Can I Back-up and Restore Amazon Aurora Database to Local Box?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to test back-up and restore. Can I restore my database from Amazon Aurora to a local box? If not, is there any on Amazon service that will let me do such thing?

Comment: Aurora is MySQL-compatible. You should be able to use MySQL clients to connect to your aurora database and backup/restore data as you would with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can backup & restore between Aurora and MySQL RDS - the backup process is same; you can automate the backup or take manual snapshots. These snapshots as per Amazon will be stored in S3 - which you can't acess or can take it to else where; you can only move the snapshots to different regions or accounts.

If the intention is to get the data out from Aurora to your local; the only way is to do a MySQL dump. Or use any 3rd party tools to backup and restore ( or sync )

I haven't tired the DataPipline approach; but you have the capability of syncing to your on-prem database ( also need to check if Aurora is supported )